# Заполнение структуры в си

Tags: c, структуры-данных

Пытаюсь инициализировать структуру начальными данными:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

struct staff {
    int code;
};

void main() {
    struct staff* s;
    int n;
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    s = (staff*)calloc(n, sizeof(staff));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf_s("%d", &s[i].code);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("\nCode: %4d, id: %d", s[i].code, i + 1);
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Так все работает, но при добавлении нового поля "name":

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

struct staff {
    int code;
    char* name; // указатель на строку
};

void main() {
    struct staff* s;
    int n;
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    s = (staff*)calloc(n, sizeof(staff));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf_s("%d", &s[i].code);
        s[i].name = (char*)malloc(10); // выделение памяти под строку
        fgets(s[i].name, 10, stdin); // ввод строки
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("\nCode: %4d, name: %10s, id: %d", s[i].code, s[i].name, i + 1);
    }
}
```

Не полностью инициализируется каждый элемент структуры, пример ввода:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код "1234" и имя "Кирилл" по логике должны были введены в 1 структуру, **как правильно их инициализировать динамически ?**

Comment: после `scanf_s`, который считал **только** число нужно убрать перевод строки из буфера

Comment: @AlexGlebe извиняюсь за глупый вопрос, но можете номер строки указать, какую убрать ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После `scanf`, который считал только число нужно убрать перевод строки из буфера функцией `fgets`. Считывать имя этой функцией не надо, она записывает в конце строки символ переноса строки. В основном, эта функция используется для файловых операций, где важна каждая мелочь. Имя считываем функцией `scanf`.

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &s[i].code);
    s[i].name = malloc(10); // выделение памяти под строку
    
    // после считывания числа очищаем оставшиеся символы и перевод строки
    fgets(s[i].name, 10, stdin);
    
    // fgets(s[i].name, 10, stdin); // ввод строки

    // имя считываем БЕЗ символа переноса строки
    // максимум девять букв плюс нулевая буква '\00'
    scanf("%9s", s[i].name);
}
```

*компилируйте как код C, а не C++*

Comment: Благодарю за помощь !